# Install haltech install on ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, software-installation

I am trying to install haltech on ubuntu, I don t know exactly how, can you help me to figure out please?
I have a ubuntu 20.04 LTS version

Comment: What is "haltech"? Is it a program or device? Please add details to the question.

Comment: https://www.haltech.com/downloads/software/ <- This ones? Don't bother. It's software for Windows and even if it could be installed with Wine (it can't) it wouldn't work (no hardware access). Use Windows in dual-boot (preferable) or a Virtual Machine.